# Custom code while deleting webpart from sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

i am developing a webpart. here i have some n number of configurations in webpart's properties. Using that configuration the webpart will show some output. The configuration will take more time to complete, so when the user delete the webpart i need to ask confirmation from the end user. How can i do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to [WebPartDeleting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms157586) event of [SPWebPartManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.spwebpartmanager_members.aspx) in the master page and write your custom code to check the configurations there.